# How do I replace \xc3 etc. with umlauts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have an output of `spannkr \xc3\xa4ftig, da\xc3\x9f unser` in Python. How do I replace this with umlauts?

Comment: Where did the output come from?

Comment: `print(str(documents[sims[i][0]]))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The German characters are already there, but encoded as utf-8.  If you want to see the umlauts etc in the interpreter then you can decode to `str`:

```
>>> bs = b'spannkr \xc3\xa4ftig, da\xc3\x9f unser'
>>> s = bs.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(s)
spannkr äftig, daß unser
```

It's possible that you are dealing with a `str` that somehow contains utf-8 encoded data.  In this case you need to perform an extra step:

```
>>> s = 'spannkr \xc3\xa4ftig, da\xc3\x9f unser'
>>> bs = s.encode('raw-unicode-escape')  # encode to bytes without double-encoding
>>> print(bs)
b'spannkr \xc3\xa4ftig, da\xc3\x9f unser' 
>>> decoded = bs.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(decoded)
spannkr äftig, daß unser
```

There isn't an easy way to distinguish between incorrectly embedded spaces and the spaces between words.  You would need to use some kind of spellchecker or natural language application.

Comment: `bs = 'spannkr \xc3\xa4ftig, da\xc3\x9f unser'` -> `bs = str.encode(bs)` -> `s = bs.decode('utf-8')` -> `print(s)` gives `spannkr Ã¤ftig, daÃ unser` to me. Also, how to remove the space in `spannkr äftig` at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for updating. Next time write a quick comment that you did, I almost missed it. I did a `.replace(' \\','\\')` in documents.